# webbrowser control in windows form not log in

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Windows form has webbrowser control which  logins to pages.
when i click the exe on server it log ins.however when i run the exe from asp.net page using process, logins fails. I think webbrowser not use the cookies while running under process of asp.net page.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\ceza\";
        process1.StartInfo.FileName = @"WindowsCezaPuani.exe";
        process1.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
        process1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        process1.Start();
```

How can i overcome this problem ? or the problem raising from webbrowser cookies ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be caused by different identity used. When starting the process from asp.net pages, the process is running under the application pool identity by default.

You can try to set the application pool identity to your computer logon account.

Follow the link below for the steps to set identity of your application pool.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170%28v=WS.10%29.aspx